# Can I tell GHC to just typecheck my code without actually compiling it?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm prototyping and messing around with the types in my program and I currently use `ghc --make` whenever I want to do a type check. However, this command also spends time to compile and link a real executable that I don't need just yet. Is there some flag I can pass to `ghc` to tell it to do just the typechecking?

Comment: I just added a caveat to the answer that was given to me: in-exhaustive patterns are not checked.

Answer (score 13):

Passing the `-fno-code` flag to ghc will do what you need.

```
$ ghc -fno-code myfile.hs
```

Answer (score 3):

GHCi will type-check your code and compile it, but will generally be much faster than GHC even with `-O0`. If that's not sufficient, there are also programs like [hdevtools](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hdevtools) and [ghc-mod](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-mod) that exist for this purpose -- they're generally meant to be integrated with a text editor but can also be used standalone.

(Another option that might speed things up a bit with just the regular compiler is `-S`, which stops after generating assembly without assembling or linking.)